# cvtColor assertion failed ( OpenCV with C++ )

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a

```
cv::Mat image;
```

object, which I loaded an image to from a file, it reads it correctly and all.

Now I have written a function to transform it to grey color.

```
cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

And this error comes up:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 2834
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:2834: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

what could be the problem?

This is how I read the image (through an imagehandler class which has a member cv::Mat m_image)

```
imagehandler::imagehandler(const std::string& fileName)
: m_image(imread(fileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR))
{
        if(!m_image.data)
{
    cout << "Failed loading " << fileName << endl;
}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you read `image` as a color image?

Comment: Check out [imread](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) .How do you read yours in your code?

Comment: I do read it as a color image.
check out main post for how I read.

Comment: What do you mean main post? You say that you load an image from a file but you don't show the code of how you load it.

Comment: please check again in the question! I edited it and inputted on how I read it in the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using different dst image:

```
cv::Mat grayImage;
cv::cvtColor(image, grayImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

Comment: The error is gone! but now Im having the problem that I cant copy this new image to a certain image.
Will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Try image.clone() for coping images

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!image.empty()) {
    //your_code
} else
    std::cout<<"Emty "
```

check the matrix before you convert.

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code.  Thanks