# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error for HoughCircles

Tags: python, opencv, nonetype

I'm trying to recreate this code to plot hough transform of a circle but I get a TypeError on the "Hough Transform for circles" line. Please help me understand why I might be getting that error.

```
def fit_circle_houghtransform(vec_x, vec_y):
"""
    use hough transform to fit circle:
    http://www.janeriksolem.net/2012/08/reading-gauges-detecting-lines-and.html
    """

#load image
im = cv2.imread("gauge1.jpg")

#create a version to draw on and blurred version
draw_im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

m,n = im.shape

#Hough transform for circles
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(im, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 10, np.array([]), 20, 60, m/10)[0]
c = circles[0]

cv2.circle(draw_im, (c[0],c[1]), c[2], (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imshow("circles", im)
cv2.waitKey()

#save imgae
cv2.imwrite("ell.jpg", draw_im)
```

The is what the exact error is:

```
File "fit_circle_houghtransform.py", line 43, in fit_circle_houghtransform
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(im, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 10, np.array([]), 20, 60, m/10)[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1):

The function call:

```
cv2.HoughCircles(im, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 10, np.array([]), 20, 60, m/10)
```

return `None`, so the `[0]` item index failed. I guess no images where detected.

Comment: So, I tried to load a new image but now I get this error:draw_im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.error: /Users/sumrania/packages/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3355: error: (-215) scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) in function cvtColor

Comment: @snazzili: That's telling you to use a 3 or 4 channel colour picture instead; see [cvtColor assertion failed ( OpenCV with C++ )](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13477694)

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second part of your question (in your comment...)

> > So, I tried to load a new image but now I get this error:
> >
> > draw_im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
> >         cv2.error: /Users/sumrania/packages/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3355:
> >         error: (-215) scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) in function cvtColor

Your new input image is colour, your code is expecting grayscale (which is what HoughCircles needs).

First you need to convert it to gray for the HoughCircles process. Assuming the original is RGB:

```
  gray_im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

This line:

```
  draw_im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

creates a colour version of the grayscale image for drawing the circles onto *after* they have been found in gray_im. It's just to get a grayscale result with coloured circles drawn on. You don't really need it if you'd rather draw the circles onto your original image.

Coincidentally I answered the same question earlier today regarding the C++ version...
[Convert Image Color from Grayscale to RGB OpenCV C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571790/convert-image-color-from-grayscale-to-rgb-opencv-c/14572028#14572028)

Comment: So, I commented the draw_im and used only gray_im everywhere but now my script is taking too long to run. It didn't show any errors and I had to manually exit.

Comment: @snazzili - if you feed gray_im to your `cv2.circles()` function you will have a conflict, as you are also sending it an RGB color spec `(0,255,0)`. Try using your colour input image here. Also ... you do know that the program halts here: `cv2.waitKey()` waiting for keyboard input. If you still can't get it to work, raise a new question showing your current code.

Comment: yeah I was aware of the waitKey function. thanks for greater insight into my function! :)